# updating base64_encode() serialized array on MYSQL Databases?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

after saving base64_encode() serilized array now I do have a problem on how to update the data

```
Array
(
    [dates] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2012-01-18
            [1] => 2012-02-18
            [2] => 2012-03-18
            [3] => 2012-04-18
            [4] => 2012-05-18
        )

    [amount] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2000
            [1] => 2000
            [2] => 2000
            [3] => 2000
            [4] => 2000
        )

    [deposit] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 0
        )

)
```

for example I want to update the value of `[deposit][2]` where `[dates][2]`  2012-03-18

I have no idea on how to update the base64_encode() serilized array, is this posible to  make?

-> after hearing from expert answer I do change my database structure with Col. Shrapnel advice thank you so much to all response

Comment: Presumably you'll have to fetch the data from the database, `base64_decode()` it, unserialize it, change the value, and then re-serialize it, re-encode it, and update the database record(s). There's no sane way to query within encoded, serialized structures in a relational database, much less update them, which is one of several reasons why you should work with the database's built-in data types instead of against them.

Comment: You'll need to extract the data, base64_decode it, update the array, base64_encode it and save it back to the database.
While you're looping through your entire database to find matching records, it may be a good time to change the storage of your data to something you can query in the future.

Comment: thank you for all response , is there any example code?

Comment: There is tons of example code how to update a field in the database. Please do some homework before asking a question here. The community will honour that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is why storing base64 encoded serialized data in the database is **extremely bad idea**.

You have to redesign your database, getting rid of base64_encode and serialized data.
While using base64 with database makes absolutely no sense by any means, storing serialized data in the database is like mending an electronic device with stone hammer.

The main difference between database and ancient scroll of parchment is to give an individual access to whatever bit of information, and you are ruined that purpose completely, using stone-age way of storing data. Please, educate yourself and learn proper ways of using databases.

Database itself IS a perfect storage for the data structure from your example. You just have to add another table with fields `date`, `amount`, `deposit` and `record_id` and link that table to one that currently contains that base64 encoded array.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, Im now thinking on how I can restructure my table

Answer (score 2):

Do not store frequently updated data using any encode, serialize methods. You are actually storing the array in Encoded form, it is not serialized.

You will be having more problems issue with `base64` Encoded arrays, You can not easily retrieve back them in the original form. `base64_decode` returns string back to you.

If the returned string is a valid array syntax you can still convert it back to array using `eval`. However, I would not recommend using this method.

If you needs to store array or object in database use the [`serialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) method and while retrieving array, object back you can use the [`unserialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) method on that.

Comment: ok got thank you, I use only serilize saving into database but don't know to how to update do you know how it should save base from my example above?

Comment: Another good serialization is `json_encode` - `json_decode`. It's a bit more verbose than `serialize` and `unserialize`, but human-readable and ready to be fetched to javascript.

Comment: you will be having original array after passing the serialized data through unserialize function, update the array and convert it back in serialized form and update the database

Comment: Leave my answer alone. If you have objections, either leave a comment of flag the answer. But keep your hands off the text. Thank you.